$A_{11}$ has no subgroups of order $\frac{11!}{14}$?
This is a question posed on a qualifying exam from the past. I have elected to answer it.
Let $A_{11}$ be the 11th alternating group (that is, $|A_{11}| = 11!/2$.) Prove that $A_{11}$ has no subgroups of order $11!/14$.

Note to other users: There is an attempt at an answer by the OP below.

SOLUTION: Assume by way of contradiction that there exists $H \leq A_{11}$ with $|H| = 11!/14.$ Let $A_{11}/H$ be the set of left cosets of $H$ in $A_{11}$; e.g. the set of all $\sigma H$ for $\sigma \in A_{11}$. (We make no claims of any group structure for $A_{11}/H$.)
By Lagrange's theorem, $|A_{11}/H| = [A_{11} : H] = \dfrac{|A_{11}|}{|H|} = \dfrac{11!/2}{11!/14}=7.$
Now consider the group action of $A_{11}$ on $A_{11}/H$ where $\sigma_{1} \cdot (\sigma_{2} H) = \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}H$. This action induces a group homomorphism $\varphi: A_{11} \to S_{7}$, since $|A_{11}/H| = 7$.
Now consider $\ker(\varphi)$. $A_{11}$ is simple, since $A_{n}$ is simple for $n \geq 5$. Since the kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup, and $A_{11}$ is simple, we see that $\ker(\varphi)$ is either trivial or $A_{11}$ itself.
In the former case, we have that $\ker(\varphi)$ is trivial, and so $\varphi$ is injective. Then $|A_{11}| \leq |S_{7}| \implies 11!/2 \leq 7!$, which is a contradiction.
In the latter case, $\ker(\varphi)$ is all of $A_{11}$, and so $\varphi$ is the trivial homomorphism. Then the original group action must have been trivial as well.
But $H \neq A_{11}$ and $H \leq A_{11}$, so there exists some $\sigma_{0} \in A_{11} - H$. And under the group action, $\sigma_{0} \cdot H = \sigma_{0} H \neq H$ since $\sigma_{0} \not \in H$. So the group action is not trivial, a contradiction.
Both cases lead to contradictions; therefore, no such subgroup $H$ exists.
